# How to build an Android application like "Chrome To Phone"

Tags: android, google-chrome

Chrome to Phone allows users to send Weblinks to an android device. It seems, that this links are being stored in the google cloud. With the "Chrome to Phone" app from google you can then retrieve them.

My question is, does Google provide any framework that allows developers to access their Cloud and retrieve data from it?

I plan to build an app like "Chrome to Phone", but so far I don't know, what is the best way to start.

Comment: does the app ask for credentials (Google account) ?

Comment: What did you try? What are you having trouble with? Are you asking whether it's possible to send an HTTP request?

Comment: yes, the app asked for credentials. I only want to know whether there is any API that allows me to access the Google Cloud Messaging service. And if so, which one is it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It seems, that this links are being stored in the google cloud

AFAIK, they are only sent to the app via Google servers, using [Google Cloud Messaging (GCM)](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html).

Comment: Thanks. This might help me already. Now I can take a look at the android documentation to find out, how I can retrieve data that is being sent to the GCM.